# Masking elements behind fixed transparent area

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div `container1` that contains different elements like other divs or svgs.

These elements can scroll up and down `container1`

But now there is an area of `container1` where these elements should not be visible, while `container1` itself is still normally visible. I have to mask them somehow with an invisible element!

In the following explanatory image you can see:

1. `container1` : red area
2. elements within `container1` : black
3. area where `container1` is visible but the elements aren't : orange rectangle

It is important though, that the parts of the elements, for example of an svg, that aren't behind that area, are still visible!

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hpl3J.png)

Is there some way to mask a specific area?

Answer (score 0):

If the elements behind your "orange rectangle" are hidden it's because the "orange rectangle" have a background. The HTML elements (like span, div, p, etc) cannot hide elements behind them unless those elements have a background.
If the orange rectangle have a background, the elements behind it will be hidden, but you can bring the elements behind the rectangle to front with `z-index` property.